# How to get coordinates of ToolStripButton?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, coordinates, toolstripbutton

How can I get coordinates of `ToolStripButton`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 Rectangle rc = toolStripButton1.Bounds;
```

Relative from the ToolStrip.  Use PointToScreen/Client to map.