# How to open form at toolstrip button position

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripitem

I have toolstrip menu with some buttons, menu is located in toolstrip container. What I am trying to accomplish is to open new form exactly at specific toolstripbutton location... This is my code. It works unless I move toolstrip menu to bottom or right side of toolstrip container...

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton rbRunMacro;
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip tsMacroRecorder;

        private void rbRunMacro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = this.rbRunMacro.Bounds;
        Point location = PointToScreen ( new Point(this.tsMacroRecorder.Location.X + rect.X, this.tsMacroRecorder.Location.Y + rect.Y));
        MacroListForm form = new MacroListForm();
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        form.Location = location ;
        form.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the location of `rbRunMacro` relative to the entire screen (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998076/getting-the-location-of-a-control-relative-to-the-entire-screen)).

```
form.Location = this.tsMacroRecorder.PointToScreen(rbRunMacro.Bounds.Location);
```

The reason we use `ToolStrip.PointToScreen` is that `ToolStripButton` does not offer the `PointToScreen` method. Therefore, we have to use `ToolStripButton.Location` to get the location of `rbRunMacro` relative to its parent control (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905088/how-to-get-coordinates-of-toolstripbutton)).

Comment: Thank you that works - except you have to reference toolstrip, because toolstripbutton does not accept PointToScreen method.